# Suppose $f: X \to Y$ is continuous. Then $\forall A \subset X$, $f(A')$ $\subset$ $f(A)'$. Prove or disprove.

Tags: general-topology

**Problem: Suppose $f: X \to Y$ is continuous. Then $\forall A \subset X$, $f(A')$ $\subset$ $f(A)'$. Prove or disprove.**

Definition of a function to be continuous: Let $(X,T_X)$ and $(Y,T_Y)$ be topological spaces. A function $f : X \to Y$ is said to be continuous iff (if and only if) for every $V \in T_Y$, $f^{-1}(V) \in T_X$.

This is how I did it.

Suppose, $f: X \to Y$ is continuous, here we have $A'$ as the limit point of $A$. I have taken X and Y as the real number line with usual topologies, and then I will define

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = 0$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, let $A = [0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $A' = [0,1]'$, and clearly $[0,1]' = [0,1]$ as every point of $[0,1]$ is a limit point of $[0,1]$ under the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

Therefore, $f(A')$ = {$0$}, and again $f(A)$ = {$0$} which implies that $f(A)' = \emptyset$ since {$0$} is finite and therefore it has no limit points.

Therefore, $f(A')$ = {$0$} and $f(A)' = \emptyset$ which clearly implies that both are not subsets of each other. Therefore, $f(A')$ = {$0$} is not a subset of $f(A)' = \emptyset$. So the remark is not true. Its a false statement.

I hope I am correct, although I didn't use the definition of a function to be continuous. Is there a way this problem can be solved using that definition? Kindly help me out on this. Appreciate your help and support.

Comment: Is $A'$ denoting the set of limit points of $A$?

Comment: Your example is fine, though you should at least mention that your function $f$ is continuous. That’s the only use of continuity that you need for a counterexample; you would use the definition of continuity (or facts about continuous functions) only if you were actually proving the result.

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 yeah that's true.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott do I need to show that my function which I defined from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous? Its crystal clear if you take a look at it but still I will show it is continuous.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun: I just meant that since you wouldn’t have a counterexample if $f$ weren’t continuous, it would be best to mention that it is. I agree that this is so obvious that no proof is actually needed here.